# Testing throws from recursion

Tags: recursion, clojure

I can't catch throws from second recursive call from `map`.
For some reason, exceptions bubbles from `(call-rec (first node))` but not from `(map call-rec node)`.

Consider following example:

```
    (deftest recursion-test
      (testing "Testing recursion throws" ;; => OK
        (is (thrown? Exception
                     (map #(throw (Exception. "e") [:a :b])))))

      (testing "Testing throws from recursion lvl 1" ;; => OK
        (is (thrown? 
             Exception
             (letfn [(call-rec [node]
                       (cond 
                        (vector? node)
                        (do
                          (throw (Exception. "e"))
                          (map call-rec node))
                        :else 
                        node))]
               (call-rec [:one :two])))))   

      (testing "Testing throws from map recursion lvl 2" ;; => FAILURE
        (is (thrown? Exception
                     (letfn [(call-rec [node]
                               (cond 
                                (vector? node)
                                (map call-rec node)

                                :else 
                                (throw (Exception. "e"))
                                ))]
                       (call-rec [:one :two])))))

      (testing "Testing throws from first recursion lvl 2" ;; => OK
        (is (thrown? Exception
                     (letfn [(call-rec [node]
                               (cond 
                                (vector? node)
                                (call-rec (first node))

                                :else 
                                (throw (Exception. "e"))
                                ))]
                       (call-rec [:one :two]))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Laziness. The form

```
(map call-rec node)
```

creates a lazy sequence that never gets realised, thus never gets the chance to throw an exception. Try the eager version:

```
(mapv call-rec node)
```

Or realise the sequence outside of `call-rec` using:

```
(doall (call-rec [:one :two]))
```

Comment: Also it's worth to mention that there are other bugs in the code. For example `(map #(throw (Exception. "e") [:a :b]))` should be `(map (fn [_](throw (Exception. "e"))) [:a :b])`. `map` with one argument will create mapping transducer in Clojure 1.7.